# Remove duplicated columns in matrix

Tags: r

I have a data set of dimension 401*5677. Among the column of this matrix there are columns which are identical but under different column names.
Now, I want to keep only one column from the columns which are repeated more than once, and also get the index j for the columns removed.

Let us use as an example matrix, the following:

```
B=matrix(c(1,4,0,2,56,7,1,4,0,33,2,5), nrow=3)
colnames(B)<-c("a","b","c","d")
```

What I did so far (on my real matrix G) is:

```
corrG<-cor(G) 
Gtest=G
for (i in 1:nrow(corrG)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(corrG)){
    if (i<j && corrG[i,j]==1){ 
      Gtest[,j]=NA
    }
  }
}
Gfinal<-Gtest[,complete.cases(t(Gtest))]
```

My code returns a matrix that still contains (!) some duplicated columns.
Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try `duplicated` function on transpose of the matrix.

```
duplicated.columns <- duplicated(t(your.matrix))

new.matrix <- your.matrix[, !duplicated.columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

One line answer

```
B = matrix(c(1, 4, 0, 2, 56, 7, 1, 4, 0, 33, 2, 5), nrow = 3)
colnames(B) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

B
##      a  b c  d
## [1,] 1  2 1 33
## [2,] 4 56 4  2
## [3,] 0  7 0  5

B[, !duplicated(t(B))]
##      a  b  d
## [1,] 1  2 33
## [2,] 4 56  2
## [3,] 0  7  5
```

Comment: yes, 1 line. But OP wanted indices of columns removed. So I had an extra line of code ;-)

Comment: Yes I need the indices, because I also have a vector which has length equal to the columns' number. So, whenever I remove a column from the matrix, I also need to remove the corresponding element from this vector. :)

Comment: I though that this would be the solution to my problem (i.e removing duplicated columns), but it seems that I miss something. The truth is that I need to get a full rank (by block) matrix. The blocks in my matrix are defined by the vector I told you before. Thus, if the first 50 elements of the vector are equal to 1, that means that the first 50 columns of the matrix belong to the group 1 etc.

Comment: Do you know how can I get block-wise full rank matrix??

Comment: I would suggest that it should be posted as a separate question.