# r-How to pick up columns with same number in each rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r

Sorry for asking this naive question, but it's really hard for me.

I have a matrix that has about 5000 columns and 80 rows, I was wondering how can I pick up the columns that have the same number in each row (cell) across 80 rows?

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904668/remove-duplicated-columns-in-matrix seems relevant.

Comment: It's always easier to answer questions if there's some kind of reproducible example in the code.  Try making a small example, and outputting it using `dput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe or matrix is called `df`, try:

```
which(apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)
```

This works because applying `length(unique(x))` to a column `x` will tell you exactly how many distinct items there are in the column.  If there's only one, then it's one of the columns with repeating rows which you're looking for.

The `apply` part runs this logic over every column in your matrix/dataframe.

The `which(... == 1)` part gives you the index of the columns which are just repeating.

Comment: Hi lebelinoz, Thank you for your kind reply! It worked! Just had a following up question, if I wanted to remove those columns in the matrix, what will be the easiest way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df[,-which(apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)]`.  Please accept the answer which I've already given if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciated your help!